# Shortestpath query returns many paths instead of one path

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

below Shortestpath query returns many paths instead of one path.

```
  MATCH PATHS=shortestPath((a:Endpoint{ nodeName: 'BRS-PE-SR7-X03B' }) -[*]-(b:Endpoint{ nodeName: 'LDN-PE-SR7-X03C' })  RETURN PATHS
```

Can anybody explain how iternally it calculates the paths and return the shortest path for the below scenarios.

My understanding is it should return ONLY one path.Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SHORTESTPATH` function finds the single shortest path between two *specific nodes*.

If multiple `Endpoint` nodes can have the same `nodeName` value, this can explain why you are getting multiple shortest paths.

If this is the reason for your results, at least one of the 2 counts returned by this query should exceed 1:

```
MATCH
  (a:Endpoint{ nodeName: 'BRS-PE-SR7-X03B' }),
  (b:Endpoint{ nodeName: 'LDN-PE-SR7-X03C' })
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT a), COUNT(DISTINCT b);
```

Comment: Thanks cybersam.I will check the nodes if they have same values

Answer (score 1):

The shortest path algorithm as provided by the REST API provides ALL SHORTEST PATHS between two nodes. This implies that if the minimum number of hops are same in more than one path, then you will get all of those shortest paths.

(https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-find-all-shortest-paths).